# Session timeout using Membership of ASP.Net in prod, not in dev environment

Tags: asp.net, session, timeout, asp.net-membership, membership-provider

When I login to my webform in my production environment ( IIS 7.5 + SQL Server 2008), my session expires after just a few couple of seconds (less than 1 minute).
But when I do the same in my dev environment (ASP.Net Development Server + SQL Server 2008) the session is persistant long enough... (several minutes).
I use the ASP.Net membership technology with Forms authentication mode and try to use Cookies.
It look like something on the server is overriding my parameters, but I don't have access to the production IIS configuration (I subscribed to a shared hosting)

Here are my web.config parmeters:

```
  <system.web>
    <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.0">
      <assemblies>
        <add assembly="System.Data.Entity, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" />
      </assemblies>
    </compilation>
    <authentication mode="Forms">
      <forms loginUrl="~/Pages/Front/Login.aspx"
             protection="All"
             timeout="900"
             path="/"
             requireSSL="false"
             slidingExpiration="true"
             defaultUrl="~/Pages/Front"
             cookieless="UseCookies"
             name="MySite" />
    </authentication>
    <membership defaultProvider="AspNetSqlMembershipProvider">
      <providers>
        <clear />
        <add name="AspNetSqlMembershipProvider"
             type="System.Web.Security.SqlMembershipProvider, System.Web, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a"
             connectionStringName="XXX"
             enablePasswordRetrieval="false"
             enablePasswordReset="true"
             requiresQuestionAndAnswer="true"
             applicationName="/"
             requiresUniqueEmail="false"
             passwordFormat="Hashed"
             maxInvalidPasswordAttempts="5"
             minRequiredPasswordLength="5"
             minRequiredNonalphanumericCharacters="0"
             passwordAttemptWindow="10"
             passwordStrengthRegularExpression=""/>
      </providers>
    </membership>
    <roleManager enabled="true"
                 cookieName="booble.com"
                 cookieProtection="All"
                 cookieSlidingExpiration="true"
                 cookieTimeout="90"
                 createPersistentCookie="true"
                 cookieRequireSSL="false">
      <providers>
        <clear />
        <add name="AspNetSqlRoleProvider" type="System.Web.Security.SqlRoleProvider" connectionStringName="XXX" applicationName="/" />
        <!--<add name="AspNetWindowsTokenRoleProvider" type="System.Web.Security.WindowsTokenRoleProvider" applicationName="/" />-->
      </providers>
    </roleManager>
    <sessionState timeout="90" />
    <customErrors defaultRedirect="Error.aspx" mode="On" redirectMode="ResponseRewrite" >
      <error statusCode="404" redirect="Error404.aspx"/>
    </customErrors>
    <!-- needed because of my Provider-->
    <pages enableViewStateMac="false" />
    <siteMap enabled="true" defaultProvider="AspNetXmlSiteMapProvider">
      <providers>
        <clear />
        <add siteMapFile="Web.sitemap" name="AspNetXmlSiteMapProvider"
            type="System.Web.XmlSiteMapProvider, System.Web,  Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a"
                securityTrimmingEnabled="true" />
      </providers>
    </siteMap>

  </system.web>
```

Thanks a LOT in advance for your answers !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**The problem was coming from my shared hosting provider**, I contacted them in their help forum and on of their admin "changed" something on server-side, and now it works... they didn't want to tell me what they have modified.

FYI my shared hosting provider is named OVH.com, so if you have a session timeout problem (expiring every 30 sec to 1 min), even if you have configured your web.config correctly (to be sure,I even put my sessionState mode="SQLServer") , just contact them and they will do the necessary.

I'll post here if I get an explanation, thanks for your readings

Answer (score 1):

Check if your session timeout is being set through code too.

```
<sessionState timeout="90" />
```

and

```
cookieTimeout="90"
```

Should have worked fine. Development servers are very forgiving about session timeouts.

Developement server doesn't represent a proper IIS 7 environment

> This provides a convenient way to test your ASP.NET application 
>   without IIS 7 - however, we recommend that you configure
>   Visual Studio to test your application by using the IIS 7 environment.
>   The reasons for this are: The ASP.NET Development Server does not
>   support hosting ASP.NET applications in Integrated mode, which is the
>   default mode of operation used by IIS 7. This may introduce
>   differences in application behavior.

[Refer here](http://learn.iis.net/page.aspx/387/using-visual-studio-2008-with-iis/)

Comment: You are right I'll try both of your prpositions:
I will setup IIS on my dev computer to be able to reproduce the problem,
I will set my session timeout through code (for now I didn't know it could be usefull since everything is supposed to be defined in web.config).
I give you my feedback asap, thanks